# How to exploit calendar arbitrage?

Tags: options, implied-volatility, arbitrage

Say we are looking at European Call options in a toy environment with zero deterministic interest rates, a stock paying no dividends, no repo rates etc...

Let $C(T,K)$ be the price of a call with expiry $T$ and strike $K$.

If for $T1 < T2$, $C(T1,K) > C(T2,K)$ then this is calendar arbitrage.

Please explain how should one exploit this arbitrage opportunity.

Thank you.

Comment: Buy the T2 call and sell the T1 call.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer by @HenriK is certainly correct. However, for justification, technique such as the Jensen inequality is needed. For example, since $x^+$ is a convex function, assuming zero interest and zero divdiend,
\begin{align*}
E\big((S_{T_{2}}-K)^+ \mid \mathcal{F}_{T_1} \big) &\ge \big(E(S_{T_{2}} \mid \mathcal{F}_{T_1})-K\big)^+\\
&=(S_{T_1}-K)^+.
\end{align*}
That is, $C(T_2) - (S_{T_1}-K)^+\ge 0$. Then,
\begin{align*}
C(T_2) - (S_{T_1}-K)^+ + x > 0.
\end{align*}

> 

Alternatively, if we short the option with maturity $T_1$ and long the option with with maturity $T_2$, then we have the initial profit $x= C(T_1)-C(T_2) > 0$.

At time $T_1$, if $S_{T_1}\le K$, the shorted option expires worthless, and then we have the total profit $(S_{T_2}-K)^++x$.

On the other hand, if $S_{T_1} > K$, the option is exercised, then, we short sell the stock (i.e., borrow and sell) and receive $K$. 
At time $T_2$, if $S_{T_2} > K$, we buy the stock by paying the amount $K$ that we had received at $T_1$, and return the stock that we had short sold at $T_1$.  The net profit for our trading strategy is $x$, that is, the initial profit. On the other hand, if $S_{T_2} < K$, we buy the stock by paying $S_{T_2}$ and return the stock that we short sold at $T_1$. Note that, we had received $K$ at time $T_1$, our net profit is then $K-S_{T_2} + x>x>0$.

Comment: The mandatory no dividends, no interest rates should be placed in bold. $S_t$ must be a martingale for the Jensen inequality to hold

Answer (score 5):

You should always think: I buy the one which is too cheap and sell the one that is too expensive and figure it out.

The figuring out in this case is noting that:

- $C\geq 0$ since it will never cost you money
- The option is strictly better than $S-K$ so has a higher price.

Now to your strategy: You buy $C(T_2)$ (the cheap) and sell $C(T_1)$ (the expensive), call the difference $x>0$. At $T_1$ your position is

$C(T_2)  - \max\{S_{T_1}-K,0\} + x$

The first term we have just argued is non-negative, the second is strictly positive. Arbitrage :)

Comment: Hello! Appreciate your answer. Can you please elaborate how does one exploit if a call is priced below S-K?

Answer (score -3):

you need to check implied volatility... Calendars must be opened when IV is low, hopping that will increase, that way you will capture the volatility increase.

Comment: If you're hoping it's not really an arbitrage or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense...

Comment: This is not arbitrage